# Autodesk Forge Viewer API: WebVR Extension does available?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I try add webVR Extension using viewer API.
There is no error on console, but the webVRicon is not displayed.

How to load webVR Extension.

It's My source code:

HTML:

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://developer.api.autodesk.com/viewingservice/v1/viewers/style.min.css?v=2.13" type="text/css">
  <script src="https://developer.api.autodesk.com/viewingservice/v1/viewers/viewer3D.js?v=2.13"></script>
```

JS:

```
var viewerElement = document.getElementById("viewerMain");  
view = new Autodesk.Viewing.Private.GuiViewer3D(viewerElement, {});
view.loadExtension("Autodesk.Viewing.WebVR");
```

I'm using GoogleChrome/FF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a developer using Forge viewer, there is nothing more than just adding the following code to load the WebVR extension:
   view.loadExtension("Autodesk.Viewing.WebVR");
Your code should be all good for the initial webvr experience, the reason why the WebVRIcon does not show is because the desktop Chrome does not support WebVR by default, you can check the WebVR extension script for the detail, or you can check this website [http://www.createwebvr.com][1] for all the supported browser.

I have deployed a website https://viewervr.herokuapp.com/ with WebVR extension enabled, you can open the link within your mobile phone to check how it works.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.Oh,I got it. I’ll check  supported WebVR browser.
I’m always grateful to you.

Comment: @Zhong Wu I wasnt able to check your link all are unavailable could u please update them